# Is there a simple approach to call REST APIs from MVC3 applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest

Can you recommend a library/simple approach to calling REST API services from ASP.NET MVC3. In Nuget I see things like RESTSharp, Hammock, Craig's Utility Library. I am looking for a common helper that I can then plug in multiple services.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting a new MVC4 project comes with some default Microsoft WebApi packages for publishing and communicating with REST Apis - so if you have the opportunity to do this in MVC4 I would take it.

If not, you can still bring in the necessary nuget package into an MVC3 project to consume an api.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http
```

The you can do things in your controller/domain layer like:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var uri = "http://www.myapi.com";
var content = client.GetAsync(uri).Result.Content;
```

Comment: Aah... That was the bit of magic I was looking for, especially as I had picked up on the fact that MVC4's WebAPI helps out with this, but I would rather stay with MVC3 for the moment. Do I need .NET 4.5 to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need 4.5 installed for that package. There might be other packages required to work with the async result, but these don't need 4.5 either..

Comment: Thanks for this. Just as an after comment, I was researching this to integrate into a SMS service. While they expose a REST API, they also provide a free DLL(wraps the REST Call) which one can drop into the .NET app which then makes its easy to make the calls. While I want to learn more about REST API, it has occurred to me that good service providers will provide .NET calling class code anyway. I may revisit this later on and cut the XML message code for the POST method etc. The service in question is Esendex. I have also since discovered Twilio, but the former worked fine. Thanks again.

Comment: I want to research this Web API code more since I will use it more in MVC4. However it would be good to see some more tutorial/code which show XML messages being created and sent, and responses being received etc. Thanks. Ed